# helper method to generate a list

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I am trying to implement a Handlebars helper that will take in some data, and based on that data generate a list. After the list was generated in a helper method, I'd want to loop this list. It will be clear in the example.

The scenario is: I have some data, and as I parse through the data I want to create some custom warnings for inconsistency in that data. The method responsible to generate the warnings from raw JSON data is called `generateWarnings()`.

I have functions to compile template and render the data, defined like this:

```
function compileTemplate(targetId) {
    return Handlebars.compile($("#" + targetId).html());
}

function renderData(template, context, targetId) {
    $("#" + targetId).html(template(context));
}
```

I am calling them:

```
var warningsPlaceHolderId = "warnings_plholder";
var warningsTemplateId = "warnings_template";

var warningsTemplate = HandlebarsHelpers.compileTemplate(warningsTemplateId);
renderData(warningsTemplate, data, warningsPlaceHolderId);
```

Handlebars template:

```
<ol>
    {{#each generateWarnings this}}
        Warning description: {{this.text}}
    {{/each}}
</ol>
```

Here, `generateWarnings` helper is supposed to take my raw JSON data, create the actual list of warnings, and display each of this warnings as the element in the **HTML list**.

I registered the Helper:

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('generateWarnings', function(data) {
        return generateWarnings(data);
    });

generateAll: function(data) {
    var warning1 = {
        type: 'error',
        text: 'Testing error!'
    };

    var warning2 = {
        type: 'warning',
        text: 'Testing warning!'
    };

    var warning3 = {
        type: 'info',
        text: 'Testing info'
    };

    var arr = [];
    arr.push(warning1);
    arr.push(warning2);
    arr.push(warning3);

    return arr;
}
```

So I would expect the `text` property of these 3 warnings to be in a list, but instead I am getting an error:

**Uncaught TypeError: inverse is not a function** at renderData().

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be using `generateAll()` in your helper?

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('generateWarnings', function(data) {
        return generateWarnings(data);   // THIS SHOULD BE generateAll(data)??
    });

generateAll: function(data) {
```

Also, you are using a label?! for your function which won't be callable the way you expect.

This:

`generateAll: function(data) { ... };`

should be:

`var generateAll = function(data ) { ... };`

I have never seen a good use for labels in JavaScript.

Your approach seems to be a bit unusual (and overly complicated) as well. Why not just manipulate the data before passing it to your template? I would consider using JavaScript to generate the warnings, then attach them to your data before passing to your template. I don't see a particular reason to be using a Handlebars helper in this situation (granted, I'm not totally familiar with the problem you are trying to solve).